# Assigning a string element to a struct in an array of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, csv, struct

I am writing a function that reads various properties, including a string, from a csv file and assigns it to a relevant element of a struct which happens to be in an array of similar structs.

Whenever I attempt to assign value to:

```
materialLookup[v-1].name
```

the program crashes.

```
MaterialL
```

is a struct with a `string` element called `name` that looks like this:

```
    struct MaterialL {
    string name;
    double sigma;
    double corLength;
    double mu;
    double muPrime;
    double ep;
    double epPrime;
};
```

I have checked that I am reading the `string` from the csv file correctly and in this case, it is "Drywall". The program always crashes before I am able to `cout<<"hey";` on the next line. My only thought is that because the program doesn't know the size of the `string` before I assign it, it doesn't leave any memory for it. If so how can I rectify this?

```
   unsigned int getMatLookUp(string filename)
{
    int nLines = getNumOfLines(filename);
    cout << nLines;
    materialLookup = (MaterialL*)alignedMalloc(nLines * sizeof(MaterialL));
    ifstream file(filename);
    int v = 0;
    string value;

    if (file.is_open() && fileExists(filename))
    {
        //flush title line
        for (int p = 0; p < 6; p++){ std::getline(file, value, ',');  }std::getline(file, value);
        v++;
        //get all the materials
        while (v < nLines -1)
        {
            std::getline(file, value, ',');
            cout << value<<"\n\n";
            materialLookup[v - 1].name = value;
            cout << "hey";
            std::getline(file, value, ',');
            cout << value << "\n\n";
            materialLookup[v - 1].sigma = stod(value);
            std::getline(file, value, ',');
            materialLookup[v - 1].corLength = stod(value);
            std::getline(file, value, ',');
            materialLookup[v - 1].mu = stod(value);
            std::getline(file, value, ',');
            materialLookup[v - 1].muPrime = stod(value);
            std::getline(file, value, ',');
            materialLookup[v - 1].ep = stod(value);
            std::getline(file, value);
            materialLookup[v - 1].epPrime = stod(value);
            v++;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file when loading material lookup in function getMatLookUp press enter to continue\n";
        cin.get();
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using `new`, or better yet `std::vector`?

Comment: @NathanOliver, Probably because of the alignment, although it's possible to use a custom allocator or the new overloads of `new` in C++17 that add an alignment argument.

Comment: @chris Doesn't `new` return properly aligned memory?

Comment: Use `std::vector`. If there's a reason to use `alignedMalloc()`, he should explain why he's using it instead of `std::vector` in the question.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I imagine so (though cppreference refers to some `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` that I don't see in N4527, probably time to update). Perhaps the OP is looking for overaligned memory, though. I really have no clue, and very little alignment experience anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely that your `alignedMalloc` uses `malloc` to allocate memory instead of `new`.

While both `malloc` and `new` allocates memory, the `new` operator does something that `malloc` does not: Call constructors.

If the `name` object is not constructed then it's basically in an invalid state and using it in any way will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The solution, if you keep on insisting on using `malloc`, or use `new[]` to allocate an array of bytes, is to use *placement new* to construct the `name` object in place:

```
materialLookup = (MaterialL*)alignedMalloc(nLines * sizeof(MaterialL));
for (size_t i = i; i < nLines; ++i)
{
    new (&materialLookup[i].name) std::string;
}
```

Comment: Great it works! I'm not sure I have a proper reason to not use std::vector or new other than I've not really ever come across them before.